# How to Update a Specific Child Node Value of XML Document in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have a method like below where I am getting all the parameter value from another method, where

```
    type = DeviceParameters
    sourceXml = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
            <ProductCode>
              <DeviceParameters>
                <P65>True</P65>
                <HWVersion>1</HWVersion>
                <Test>Test</Test>
                <Test>hello</Test>
              </DeviceParameters>
              <FirmwareGates>
                <Firmware>120.0.23</Firmware>
              </FirmwareGates>
              <ModemIncludeList>
                <Modem>Test</Modem>
                <ModemFirmware>2</ModemFirmware>
              </ModemIncludeList>
            </ProductCode>
    oldParameterName= Test
    oldParameterValue= hello
    newParameterName = Test
    parameterValue = hello123
```

I am trying to update the value for the node  `<Test>hello</Test>`to                `<Test>hello123</Test>`

**EDIT:**
I have tried to Removed the parameter and readd with the new value but it seems like more difficult. Is there any way to update the value?

```
private string EditParameter(TesterParameterCodeType type, string sourceXml, string oldParameterName, string oldParameterValue, string newParameterName, string parameterValue, int index)
            {
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(sourceXml); // or XDocument.Parse(string)
            doc.Root.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name == oldParameterName && e.Value == oldParameterValue).Remove();           

                var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
                doc.Save(stringWriter);
                return stringWriter.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing XML node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16376829/removing-xml-node)

Comment: Sorry I can't find that source XML and it doesn't seems to solve my problem

Comment: Can you share what is the `TesterParameterCodeType`?

Comment: Its an enum, and here is my enaum value is DeviceParameters and its a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make InnerText property available in auto complete just change your for using the correct type of your node variable

`foreach (XmlElement node in parameterNode)`

To remove the node in your if just select the parent of you node and remove the current node from the parent:

```
if(node.InnerText == parameterValue)
{
    var parentNode = node.ParentNode;
    parentNode.RemoveChild(node);
}
```

You can see an example of your full conde in this link:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/2Fe2ss

Comment: Thanks @Lutti Coelho Can you please tell me how can I delete that node which vale is hello?
I mean in my if block what should I write?

Comment: I'v updated the answer with the `RemoveChild` example.